# SourceView and SourceRect is depreciated?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to fix all my warnings for my project, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

The warning I am given is:

**'sourceView' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: renamed to 'UIContextMenuInteraction'**

I have read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction) but i still cant figure out how to fix this warning?

Here is the code it is talking about:

```
extension CollectionsViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        
        let tableView = previewingContext.sourceView as! UITableView
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) {
            
            let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
            let touch = cell.convert(location, from: tableView)
            
            if let productResult = cell.productFor(touch) {
                previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.convert(productResult.sourceRect, from: cell)
                return self.productDetailsViewControllerWith(productResult.model)
                
            } else if let collectionResult = cell.collectionFor(touch) {
                previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.convert(collectionResult.sourceRect, from: cell)
                return self.productsViewControllerWith(collectionResult.model)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        self.navigationController!.show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate protocol changed as [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewingdelegate):

> **Deprecated**
> UseUIContextMenuInteractionDelegate instead.

So you need to remove `previewingContext` delegate method rather than change its parameter **sourceview** etc. Instead of this method you need to pick from the new protocol `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` of its
delegate methods as Apple indicated.

In other words your extension is totally outdated and you need to rewrite according to new protocol.